# Bugs in my .htaccess ! file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem in my Rewrite engine at  .htaccess file , I used this file to convert urls from `site.com/name.php?n=ahmad`  to `site.com/ahmad`

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  name.php?n=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ name.php?n=$1u
```

---

My bugs when I call page in those status I have blank white page :

1. `site.com/ahmad.s`
2. `site.com/english/`     English folder on my site but I can't show it .

how I can fix the problem  ??

Comment: Do you want to direct `name.php?n=...` page to `/...` or vice versa? Your htaccess is built for the vice-versa task.

Comment: Your regex does not accept `.` which causes problem #1. 2nd question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._-]+)/?$ /name.php?n=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon Lin so much , it's work .

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$  name.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```